# Compatible Android versions receiving incompatibility message on Google Play

Tags: android

I've researched this pretty thoroughly and so far as I can tell, all that you should have to do is use portions of the Android API the devices you're supporting will recognize, and to specify a version range in your Manifest file. I've done both of these things. (See below these paragraphs for the full Manifest file contents.)

My client has Android version 4.0.4, which should be compatible, but when she tries to download the beta via Google Play, the link says that her device (a Samsung of some sort) is incompatible.

I'm not sure what else I need to do at this point, so any advice will be a huge help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.osu.expandablelistviewtest1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Expandable List Test 1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Expandable List Test 1" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CoreConversationsActivity"
            android:label="Book 2: Core Conversations (ver. 0.1)" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DrillsActivity"
            android:label="Book 2: Drills (ver. 0.1)" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.StreamAudioActivity"
            android:label="Book 2: Streaming Audio (ver. 0.1)" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.StreamVideoActivity"
            android:label="Book 2: Streaming Video (ver. 0.1)" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What are the min & max SDK versions in your app's build.gradle file?

Comment: Is your client's device on the list of supported devices in the Google Play Developer Console -> YourAppName -> APK -> Supported Devices?

Comment: joshgoldeneagle: When using up-to-date Android Studio, you're not supposed to have to fiddle with the build.gradle file manually anymore, as I understand

Comment: @somecbusnerd not really. Although Android Studio will keep some apsects of build.gradle up-to-date, you should learn to view and edit it. The question remains: does build.gradle contain any entries for min or max sdk values?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, the issue was with the build.gradle file. Improbably, Android Studio still doesn't update the following segment on the basis of the information in the Manifest file:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.osu.expandablelistviewtest1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

In my case, minSdkVersion had been set to 16 rather than 14, leading to issues of compatibility